# What's a good translation for "unscratchable itch" in Russian?

Tags: идиомы

An "unscratchable itch" is an issue that's very important to someone, but which they can't do anything about. What would be a more or less close Russian equivalent of this phrase (apart from *журавль в небе*)?

**Update 1:**

Example of usage in a sentence:

*After Miss X dumped him and married another guy, she became Y's unscratchable itch.*

Meaning: Y can't be with Miss X, but he also can't forget her.

**Update 2:**

Another example:

*In order to write a good screenplay, it must in one way or another be related to your unscratchable itch.*

Meaning: A piece of art will only resonate with the audience if its creator put a piece of their "soul" into it, i. e. made this work of art about something they care deeply about, but can't change in real life.

Comment: _Журавль в небе_ corresponds to the English _pie in the sky_ which means “impossible, unlikely, or fanciful idea or plan”, it isn't about an important issue, it's about an unrealistic dream.

Comment: _Больное место_ can be a variant. Could you provide examples of “unscratchable itch” used in a sentence? Google says the idiom is rather rare.

Comment: @YellowSky I added an example in update 1. BTW, could it be *идея фикс*?

Comment: In #1 about love, _идея фикс_ сan well be used. In #2 about screenplay, _наболевшее_ will do. Still, I'm inclined to think that “unscratchable itch” is always about star-crossed love, not just _any_ important issue.

Comment: _Неутолимый зуд_ is the literal translation, however in a positive rather than negative context something like _неутолимая жажда_ (странствий, знаний, etc.) might be better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure "unscratchable itch" is something that applies equally well to both your examples, but if I were forced to use the same Russian idiom for both of them, I would go with *мысль … не даёт покоя*:

> Мысль о мисс X не давала покоя Y с тех самых пор, как она бросила его и вышла за другого.
>
> Чтобы сценарий вышел удачным, в нём так или иначе должно быть то, мысль о чём не даёт вам покоя.

There are couple more idioms related to this:

- *любимая мозоль*, "pet peeve, some problem that you can't stop talking about once it's mentioned". It's not an obsession but rather a conversation subject.
- *больное место, больная тема*, "sore spot, something you'd rather not talk about". Unlike the previous one, that's something you'd rather not talk about.
- *идея фикс, идефикс*, "pathological obsession with something". It's not about the state of mind but rather some belief or plan, on which one can actually act.
- *заноза в заднице, головная боль* "pain in the ass, a permanent problem you can do little about". Again, it's not about a state of mind but rather some usually definable external problem.

Comment: Upvoted!  While I don't speak Russian, I am quite familiar with the meaning of "itch you can't scratch", and I would have to say that it is an expression that doesn't imply any specific situation(love, romance, physical literal skin itching, etc), but rather implies any situation that quite annoys a person, but for which they have no possible resolution.  I would say that your last bullet #4 almost exactly explains the intended meaning.  That being said, the first three don't really apply...

Comment: I should also add that it isn't generally used to refer to general disapproval of policies or circumstances that apply to the general population.  "An itch you can't scratch" usually refers to a perceived aggression that is unique and targeted to the specific individual making the statement.  In other words, "fuel prices are high, but there is nothing I can do about it" wouldn't apply.  Accordingly, "I love this person, but they are not returning my affection and there is nothing I can do to change it" would not apply.  The irritant needs to be external and targeted at the individual person...

Answer (score 4):

I'm tempted to use the word `мечта` with some adjective here. I'm not sure if it's possible to use the same adjective for all the phrases, but it seems like `заветная` or `несбыточная` would be a better fit — At least for the meaning I gleaned from your question (I haven't come across this idiom before). Заветная refers to importance where несбыточная is about unreachability - you have to choose.

I also like the word `одержимость`, but it will require rephrasing the whole sentence.

By the way, Google translates it as `непреодолимый зуд` - it's nice to show одержимость, and I suppose it's a good translation in general, but it's difficult to put it into your examples.

And now, some translations. The ones I liked the most are in bold.

- *После того, как мисс Икс вышла замуж за другого, она стала для Игрека заветной мечтой.*

  Фраза подчёркивает, что Игрек стал ценить её после (а точнее в следствие) того, как она вышла замуж - возможно, он её до этого не особо замечал, а тут это произошло и его отношение изменилось.
- ***После того, как мисс Икс вышла замуж за другого, Игрек стал одержим ей.***

  Как предыдущий вариант, но меньше делает акцент на отношении до замужества, и сильно выражает, что он стал постоянно о ней думать после.
- *После того, как мисс Икс вышла замуж за другого, она стала для Игрека несбыточной мечтой.*

  В отличие от предыдущих не делается акцент на изменении отношения. По-прежнему выражает ценность для него, но может говорить не об изменении отношения, а об изменении статуса - до замужества было возможно, что они будут вместе, а после - уже нет.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы он так или иначе касался твоей мечты.*

  Вроде бы звучит хорошо, подчёркивает, что это что-то, что тебя волнует, о чём ты думаешь. Но есть существенный недостаток - выражает позитивную направленность и ценность, тогда как оригинальная версия говорит просто о мыслях и раздумьях, а значит автоматически включает и возможность зацикливаться на проблемах.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы он так или иначе касался твоих забот.*

  Попытка исправить недостаток прошлой версии, честно говоря, не очень удачная. Хотя слово "заботы" и может использоваться в обоих смыслах (хотя я не уверен, насколько это распространено), оно не подчёркивает раздумья. И вообще фраза становится менее выразительна.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы он так или иначе касался того, о чём ты постоянно думаешь.*

  Более корректная с точки зрения смысла фраза, но менее красивая и более размытая.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы ты был одержим им.*

  Подчёркивается актуальность и некая зацикленность на идее, и при этом абсолютно ничего нет про её положительность или отрицательность. Мне сложно вставить сюда выделение некой части сценария и получается одержимость сценарием в целом (в том числе не сюжетом, а самим написанием) вместо какой-то идеи в рамках сценария.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы ты был одержим его сюжетом.*

  Попытка исправить недостаток прошлой версии, но он лишь уменьшился - теперь исключена одержимость написанием как таковым, но сохраняется одержимость сюжетом в целом вместо акцента на деталях или идее. Можно было бы заменить "его сюжетом" на "чем-то из него", но тогда выразительность фразы падает.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо, чтобы от у тебя от него прям зудело.*

  Более красивая версия прошлой фразы. Кстати, по сути это модификация варианта "непреодолимый зуд" от Гугла. По идее "от него" вместо "от этого" по-прежнему ставит акцент на сценарий, а не его написание, хотя более неявно. Проблема с неуказанием идеи сохраняется.
- ***Для написания хорошего сценария надо взять в него что-то такое, от чего у тебя прям зудит.***

  Мне кажется, такая формулировка в наилучшей степени отражает смысл фразы - по-прежнему подчёркивается актуальность, а также говорится о том, что зацикленность должна быть не на самом сценарии, а на том, о чём он - что в нём должна быть некая сюжетная линия, которая для тебя важна, о которой ты постоянно думаешь.
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо чтобы он был о наболевшем.*

  Это версия на основе идеи из комментария [@YellowSky](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/1236/yellow-sky). Она красивая, подчёркивает актуальность и сюжетную линию, но в противовес варианту с мечтой больше склоняет в негативную сторону. Кстати, с мечтой можно сформулировать аналогично "чтобы он был о твоей мечте".
- *Для написания хорошего сценария надо чтобы он был о наболевшем... Ну или о мечте.*

  *Для написания хорошего сценария надо чтобы он был о наболевшем... Ну или о мечте...*

  Этот выставляет мечту и наболевшее в неравном свете, что на мой взгляд нехорошо. Кстати, в каком именно, будет зависеть от интонации - если вторую часть сказать пренебрежительно (скорее всего на письме будет выражаться точкой в конце), то получится, что надо о наболевшем, но сойдёт и о мечте. Если сказать вторую часть мечтательно (закончить многоточием), то будет "хотелось бы о мечте, но скорее всего придётся о наболевшем". Как красиво скомбинировать их в одну фразу так, чтобы они были равноправны, я не знаю.

PS: Надеюсь, это было полезно :)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the idiom `сохнуть по кому-либо` meaning to love somebody from a distance.

> Она бросила его и вышла замуж за другого, а он по ней всё ещё сохнет.

Comment: This does not apply.  The "itch" is an external force that you have no choice but to endure.  Loving someone from a distance is definitely something in which you have a choice...

Comment: @Hitek - if she dumped him and married another guy, he cannot do anything about the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Some suitable idiomatic translations would be:

> неисполнимое желание
>
> неисполнимая мечта
>
> неизбывная мечта
>
> непреходящая мечта
>
> вечная мечта

In context of a sentence, you could finish it with `", что так и осталось мечтой"`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at:

- близок локоть, да не укусишь
- видит око, да зуб неймёт